# At which point is ServiceLocator created?

Tags: c#, .net, prism, service-locator

I am currently developing an application using the **Prism Library 4.5**.

I am experiencing the problem with a Model which uses the **Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocator** in it's constructor. Which works perfectly fine except when I try to load this specific Model during startup, more precisely in Prisms **Bootstrapper**. The ServiceLocator is **null** at this point, so I'm wondering at which point the ServiceLocator is beeing created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified which bootstrapper you are using, but the order for the Unity Bootstrapper is:

1. CreateLogger
2. CreateModuleCatalog
3. ConfigureModuleCatalog
4. CreateContainer
5. ConfigureContainer
6. **ConfigureServiceLocator**
7. ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings
8. ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors
9. RegisterFrameworkExceptionTypes
10. CreateShell
11. InitializeShell
12. InitializeModules